# stored procedure result run by manual exec is different from run by sql server job

Tags: sql-server

the procedure is as follow:

```
CREATE or ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_staffid_test2]
AS
BEGIN
insert into staffid_Test2
   select  DBO.SALARY_VALUE_NOW_testing2() as salaryvalue,
       current_user, getdate() as credate
end;
```

it calls function DBO.SALARY_VALUE_NOW_testing2() defined as follow:

```
CREATE OR ALTER   FUNCTION [dbo].[SALARY_VALUE_NOW_testing2]()
   RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value INT;
            
    select @return_value = 1;       
    return @@ROWCOUNT;
END;
```

the table definition of staffid_Test2 is shown as follow image:
[image]

the job is defiined as follow:
[image]

if run

```
exec dbo.insert_staffid_test2;
```

manually, the salaryvalue inserted to staffid_Test2 is 1

but if run by job, the salaryvalue inserted to staffid_Test2 is 0

which mean @@ROWCOUNT return 1 when run dbo.SALARY_VALUE_NOW_testing2 manually, but @@ROWCOUNT return 0 when run dbo.SALARY_VALUE_NOW_testing2 by job,

why will this happen?

Comment: Inlining issue? The above, I assume ,is overly simplified (there is no need for a scalar function that returns a literal), so probably doesn't tell us the real picture. What, however, is the full version number of your SQL Server instance?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue (when running with or without agent) on the latest version of SQL Server 2019. I stand by an inlining issue, and that most likely you are using a old version of SQL Server 2019; most likely the original RTM build which has had 15 UC's since release (many of the early ones addressing bugs).

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: what is inlining issue? how to fix it? thanks

Comment: Good, crystal ball is working; just as I guessed. Unpatched 2019 RTM. Update your instance; it's 15 CUs behind; then test. I doubt the problem occurs any more.

Comment: then how to fix it?

Comment: As i said in the last 2 comments; update your instance.

Comment: so I should upgrade to Cumulative Update Package 15 for SQL Server 2019 - KB5008996?

Comment: That's the latest CU, yes.

Comment: anyway, what is Inlining issue?

Comment: Basically what it "says on the tin". In the initial release of SQL Server 2019, there were several issues/problems/flaws with the new inlining functionality of user defined scalar functions. Many of these were fixed in the first few CUs. Your function can be inlined, as it's overly trivial, however, as you haven't patched your SQL Server instance in the last ~2.5 years, it suffers inlining issues that have since been fixed.

Comment: [KB4538581](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d) in [CU2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4536075-cumulative-update-2-for-sql-server-2019-1c344add-96bd-0810-433e-f7f9326c393c) fixes it. The fix actually blocks inlining of UDFs that contain certain things like `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Answer (score 0):

In the initial release of SQL Server 2019, there were several issues/problems/flaws with the new inlining functionality of user defined scalar functions. Many of these were fixed in the first few CUs. Your function can be inlined, as it's overly trivial, however, as you haven't patched your SQL Server instance in the last ~2.5 years, it suffers inlining issues that have since been fixed.

[KB4538581](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d) in [CU2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4536075-cumulative-update-2-for-sql-server-2019-1c344add-96bd-0810-433e-f7f9326c393c) fixes it. The fix actually blocks inlining of UDFs that contain certain things like @@ROWCOUNT.